# Android: What is the best way to register callbacks in multiple instances item and return onEvents to instance callback?

Tags: android, performance, callback, broadcastreceiver

Background:

- Nothing special, I'm using Java for Android.

Problem:

- I want to allow my users to create multiple instances of an object and register a callback Interface into each instance (think of an error callback).
- The object has several children/sub-children/etc... Each child can return this event.
- I expect 1-10 instances in entire lifetime of app.
- I'm trying to avoid using a singleton/static events listener.

Possible solutions (and reasons not to use them):

1) Register a BroadcastReceiver in each parent-object instance and allow each grand child notify the event on Intent level. This should allow the main object to notify my user about the event.
The problem is the multiple instances would require multiple BroadcastReceivers which I expect to be heavy or just less than optimal.

2) Register one BroadcastReceiver and find a way to let it decide which instance of the object should be notified of an event, and actually send it to it. The problem is that I'm not sure how to notify the objects themselves.

3) Let the callback interface pass as an argument from parent to each of the children/grandchilren/etc... But this would be messy.

4) Use something like EventBus library (which I understand would be the same thing as BroadcastReceiver, only Reflection based, thus slower).

5) Anything else?

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're doing but how about Observer / Observable?

Comment: As far as I underatand Obsr. pattern is used for m ultiple objects listening to one object. I need one object to discern events from multiple sub-objects and notify one of multiple listener objects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution for you but I think it would work if I understand your requirements correctly.

```
public class Listener extends Observable implements Observer {

    private List<Observer> clients = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addClient(Observer client){
        clients.add(client);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        for(Observer client : clients){
            client.update(o, arg); // Or whatever you need to do
        }
    }

    public class DataSource extends Observable {

        private Observer observer;

        public DataSource(Observer o){
            observer = o;
        }

        // Notify observer of changes at appropriate time

    }

    public class Consumer implements Observer {

        public Consumer(){
            Listener listener = ...;
            listener.addClient(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
            // Handle appropriately
        }
    }
}
```

`DataSource` is your "sub-objects", `Consumer` is the end client of the events, and `Listener` is the class in the middle. I don't know why the clients can't directly register for events with the "sub-objects" but that is what you said! This is modeled as inner classes here for simplicity but I assume you would not do that.